# How to set the ExecutionException thrown by AsyncTask's get method?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, executionexception

According to the official documentation, [AsyncTask#get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) throws an ExecutionException when an exception occurs in the threaded Task. How can I notify the current AsyncTask that an exception has been thrown in the [AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) method?

Answer (score 0):

The best would be not to use `AsyncTask.get()` at all because `get()` is synchronous so you will gain nothing

Comment: The thing is I have an AsyncTaskManager object that takes AsyncTasks and manages them notifiying the caller Activity as soon as an AsyncTask finishes. It also offers some other functionality that I need. Given that, I need to be able to call the get() method when an AsyncTask finished.
For now, I'll make a workaround, but I think that part of the API wasn't quite well implemented (unless someone  actually knows how to make it work properly).

Comment: Maybe you could use an Executor submitting Runnables/Callables to it instead of AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The ExecutionException is thrown by the `Future#get()` method that is internally called by `AsyncTask#get()`.

[Futures](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) do allow to throw Exceptions within their executed asynchronous block. A call to `Future#get()` will throw such an Exception encapsulated in an ExecutionException.

AsyncTasks, however, do not allow to throw Exceptions within the `AsyncTask#doInBackground()` method. Therefore, you can't use this mechanism for your exception handling. This seems to be an architectural design decision.

Disclaimer:

You can probably still throw RuntimeExceptions in your `AsyncTask#doInBackground()`, leading to a related `ExecutionException` on `AsyncTask#get()` ... but you shouldn't ;)

Note:

Are you sure that you want to call `AsyncTask#get()` and block your calling thread? Calling it from your main/ui thread will cause your user interface to stop being refreshed until your task is finished.

Comment: I'm currently using this solution for managing AsyncTasks:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/162201/Painless-AsyncTask-and-ProgressDialog-Usage

This solution works by using the AsyncTask#get() method. I'm making a workaround, though so I can emulate the behaviour.